# How to focus z-index: 2 element and not z-index: 1

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to draw a piano with CSS and JavaScript. Here is my code :

```css
.container {
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.mix {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
}

.tile {
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    width: 45px;
    height: 240px;
}
.tile:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.black-key {
    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: black;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.black-key:active {
    background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <title>Piano App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mix"></div>
        <div class="flex justify-center">
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile">
                <div class="black-key"></div>
            </div>            
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile">
                <div class="black-key"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile">
                <div class="black-key"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile">
                <div class="black-key"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile">
                <div class="black-key"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile"></div>
            <div class="tile">
                <div class="black-key"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is :
When I click on a black key, I want it to change color (see CSS), but the problem is it focuses the with key too. So, the white key change color too.

I want only the black key to change color when I click on it.

Any idea where is my mistake ?

Comment: if you use css for, you must out black-key from tile div- but simply you can control this structure with js. why you not use js ?

Comment: @thisisnabi you mean, set an active class with js instead of CSS ?

Comment: if you use js, say. i write an example for you/

Comment: @thisisnabi yes I use JS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's too much work to separate `.black-key` from `.tile` (IDK never used Tailwind), you can change the `.black-key`s into `<a>` so they actually are focusable and then use `:focus-within` on `.tile`s. `:focus-within` is the only CSS property to affect a parent tag via it's child. Basically, if a child of a tag with `:focus-within` triggers a `"focus"` event then it's styles can change. Unfortunately, the only tags that all browsers consider focusable are `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, and `<a>`.

This may look semantically off but it's a **piano** not a form, or article (I'm talking to the semantics cops out there).

**HTML**

Change:

```html
<div class='black-key'></div>
```

To:

```
<a href='#' class='black-key'></a>
```

**CSS**

Add:

```css
.tile:focus-within {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.black-key {
  display: block;
/*...*/
```

When `.black-key` gains focus, `.tile` will just keep it's opacity/alpha (in retrospect `opacity: 1` should work as well).

**JS**

Add to index.js or a `<script>` tag located before the closing `</body>` tag (the bottom of `<body>` not under `<body>`):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.black-key').forEach(a => a.onclick = e => e.preventDefault());
```

That keeps any `.black-keys` from jumping when clicked -- it shouldn't affect anything else. Here's some corrections to CSS:

- **Removed `z-index`**  since it will only work for non-static tags:

  - `position:`

    - `relative;`,
    - `absolute;`,
    - `fixed;`, or
    - `sticky;`
- **Removed `!important`**. Unless you know exactly what you are doing not only in the present but also in the future always avoid using `!important`. Changed `width: 100% !important` to `min-width: 100%`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.black-key').forEach(a => a.onclick = e => e.preventDefault());
```

```css
.container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.mix {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgb(29, 29, 29);
}

.tile {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  width: 45px;
  height: 240px;
}

.tile:active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.tile:focus-within {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.black-key {
  display: block;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.black-key:active {
  background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">

  <title>Piano App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mix"></div>
    <div class="flex justify-center">
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile">
        <a href='#' class="black-key"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile">
        <a href='#' class="black-key"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="tile">
        <a href='#' class="black-key"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile">
        <a href='#' class="black-key"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="tile">
        <a href='#' class="black-key"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile">
        <a href='#' class="black-key"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```